# What is the proper way to write this exception handling?

Tags: python

I only want my list to have one element in it. There should be one exception raised if the list is empty and a different exception raised if the list has more than one element.

The following code accomplishes the task, but I don't think it's written as well as it should by any standards out there. Additionally, if the condition is met that the list is greater than one, I want it to print the python error "index out of range" as it does in the other condition. How can I improve upon this?

```
x = []
try:
    if len(x) > 1:
        raise Exception
    else:
        testVar = x[0]
except IndexError as e:
    print(e)
    print("list does not have any elements.")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("There are too many elements in the list.")
```

Comment: Raising an exception only to catch it like that is pointless.

Comment: "index out of range" is not the correct error here, because that doesn't describe the condition.  `ValueError` might be better.

Comment: Exceptions are for *exceptional* situations your function doesn't know how to handle and should, generally speaking, be used sparingly. They should definitely not be used for local control flow.

Comment: Thanks for all of your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better way to write that.

```
def func(x):
    if not x:
        print("list does not have any elements.")
        return None
    if len(x) > 1:
        print("There are too many elements in the list.")
        return None
    return x[0]
```

Note that if we omit the first three lines, then Python will automatically raise an IndexError when you refer to x[0].

Comment: thanks! I went with this.